# While loop lower-casing program not working in python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input

I'm having a problem with one with my teacher assignment. The assignment:

1.**Write the program which input strings**

2.**Print the strings after the lower case them.**

3.**In the last line write the amount of input lines.**

4.**Stop when found an empty line.**

This is my piece of code that is broken:

```
n=input()
c=1
while 1:
  if n=='\n':
    break
  else:
    n=n.lower()
    print (n)
    c+=1
    n=input()
print (c)
```

But my code do not seem to work. Mainly, as I debugged, I found that n == '\n' is not working. The if n == '\n' never runs, so the while loop is not stopping, making an unbreakable infinite loop.

If you can repair the problem, please tell me in the comment section. 
I tried n == '  ' but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a homework crowdsourcing platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to check for a `\n`, you just want to check for `''`.

Try this:

```
c = 0
while 1:
    n = input()
    if n == '':
        break
    else:
        print(n.lower())
        c += 1
print(c)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't think it would be so fast!

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!